# Advice on samples and noise threshold for final renders?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I recently finished modelling and texturing a couch and I am ready to render. My initial renderings lose a lot of detail and most of the textures aren't readable. I played around with the render settings (samples, noise threshold, etc.) but I am not seeing any noticeable difference. There seems to be much more detail in the [Viewport display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnpFi.jpg) as opposed to the [final render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dRwi.png). How do I increase the level of detail in the final render?

Comment: what does it give if you increase the resolution?

Comment: A much better result lol. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's just a problem of resolution, increase it in the *Output* panel, in pixel, also make sure that it is 100%:

[image]

Comment: Maybe describe in a little more detail what image resolution is, and how exactly to increase it. Yes, they should already know that, but they don’t.

Comment: Sure, I've edited  ;)